# How can I selectively access elements returned by a Perl subroutine?

Tags: arrays, perl, subroutine

Say a Perl subroutine returns an array:

```
sub arrayoutput
{
    ...some code...
    return @somearray;
}
```

I want to access only a specific array element from this, say the first. So I could do:

```
@temparray=arrayoutput(argument);
```

and then refer to `$temparray[0]`.

But this sort of short reference doesn't work: `$arrayoutput(some argument)[0]`.

I am used to Python and new to Perl, so I'm still looking for some short, intuitive, python-like way (`a=arrayoutput(some argument)[0]`) to get this value. My Perl programs are getting very long and using temporary arrays like that seems ugly. Is there a way in Perl to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Slices](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub foo {
    return 'a' .. 'z'
}

my $y = (foo())[3];
print "$y\n";

__END__

d
```

Alternately, you do not need an intermediate variable:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub foo {
    return 'a' .. 'z'
}

print( (foo())[7], "\n" );

if ( (foo())[7] eq 'h') {
    print "I got an h\n";
}

__END__

h
I got an h
```

Comment: Note that `print (foo())[7]` won't work as expected, since perl assumes that the parentheses belong to the function call, and thus parses it as equivalent to `(print foo())[7]`. Either `print( (foo())[7] )` or, more idiomatically, `print +(foo())[7]` will work, though.

Answer (score 16):

Pull off the first argument only via list context:

```
my ( $wanted ) = array_returning_sub( @args );
```

TIMTOWTDI with a slice:

```
my $wanted = ( array_returning_sub( @args ) )[0];
```

---

Both styles could be extended to extract the n'th element of the returned array, although the list slice is a bit easier on the eye:

```
my ( undef, undef, $wanted, undef, $needed ) = array_returning_sub( @args );

my ( $wanted, $needed ) = ( array_returning_sub( @args ) )[2,4];
```

Comment: Read as `"array-returning sub"`, not `"array returning [a] sub"`

Comment: Except subs can't return arrays. They can only return lists of scalars.

Comment: +1. So it was just a question of brackets! List slice is also better that list context for long lists.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be `[(arrayoutput(some argument))]->[0]`.

Comment: +1, this works! I don't understand why this is being downvoted. Is there some bad programming practice or something else going on here that I'm missing?

Comment: There is no need to use an array reference. I guess that is the reason for the downvote.